# Searching for a Specific Text Font in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts, alignment

Is there a text font in Excel for which all words with the same number of letters share the same space horizontally? For example, one of my column is

> AAACCEINPU
>
> AABBEILMTT
>
> AABCEILLMP
>
> AABDEILNNS
>
> AABEEGILLN
>
> AABEFIILNS
>
> AABEGGILNN
>
> AABEGIILMN
>
> AABEIILLLN
>
> AABEIILMMR
>
> AABEIILNRV
>
> AABEILLMPP
>
> AABEILLNSS
>
> AABEILLORS
>
> ...

and when I'm going to print it I would prefer all the words to end at the exact same place horizontally. That is, in

> AAACCEINPU|
>
> AABBEILMTT|
>
> AABCEILLMP|

I want all the | characters to be aligned vertically, but without having ugly spaces in a word in order to do so.

**So, is there a font that does this? If not, is there a way to achieve the desired result?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're referring to is called a monospace font.  The most common one is probably Courier.  Font names with the word "mono" in it are monospace fonts, as well as "console", "terminal", "OCR", and "fixed" fonts.  Prestige Elite and Letter Gothic are also monospace.  This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_monospaced_typefaces) contains samples of common ones of different styles.